# posting list to the controller from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view, which generates rows dynamically and from where I want to submit the data to the controller. So I am binding the model properties with a list, but on httppost my list is always null.Using form collection I am able to get the data.  How can I solve this issue?

```
<td data-title="Product Name">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-right:0px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model._list[Model.id].detail_prod_id, Model._Product, "Please Select Product", new { @class = "chosen-select form-control", @id = "ddlproducts" + Model.id ,@Name= "ddlproducts" +Model.id})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._list[Model.id].detail_prod_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right:25px; padding-left:5px;"><a class="popup-sm fancybox.iframe" href="../pages/add-product.html"><u>Add</u></a></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Show the relevant code! You model. The controller methods, how you generate the partial view dynamically. Its not binding because your `name` attributes no not match the model!

Comment: After removing the name. I am getting the list. Thank You.

Comment: Under no circumstance do you ever attempt to set the `name` (or `value`) attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods :)

Comment: I set the name for accessing the elements using form collection in a loop inside the controller. I ll definitely remember this next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put code inside form tag and then try..it may work.

Comment: there is a form tag in the main view. You mean I ll add a form tag in the partial view also?

Comment: yap..It will submit only partial view...not the main view

Comment: No, the list is still null.

Comment: add button inside form and submit through it..you acting like You are completely new with mvc..

Comment: Read the question - OP already has a form and its already submitting!